# facebook not fetching the logo of website

Tags: wordpress, facebook, debugging

The homepage link of website posted in share box of facebook fetches a old image of the old story but not the logo of website.
In the header file of my wordpress theme i made the following change

```
<!--FB image-->
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if (is_single() || is_page()) {$fbthumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'slider'); echo 

$fbthumb[0];} else {echo 'http://clientdemo.crayoninfotech.com/boomnews/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/logofb1.jpg';}?>" />
```

The problem is still  after passing the correct link of logo facebook take some other random image from one of website old story.

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this it took a while before it showed up on FB. Use this to see the effect of your code changes: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug